# Error: Error when reading 'pub': No such file or directory

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to set up a Dart project to use [shelf](https://pub.dev/packages/shelf). Now to enable hot reload, I am trying to install [dartman](https://pub.dev/packages/dartman). On doing

```
pub global activate dartman
```

Command 'pub' not found, did you mean:

The I try

```
dart pub global activate dartman
```

and I get **Error: Error when reading 'pub': No such file or directory**

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What version of the Dart SDK do you have installed?  The `dart pub ...` error indicates that you are using an older version of Dart.

Comment: I using Dart SDK version: 2.9.2 (stable) (Wed Aug 26 12:44:28 2020 +0200) on "linux_x64"

Comment: @RavgeetDhillon you are using `2.9.2 , Wed Aug 26 12:44:28 2020`,  but latest version is `2.12.2 / 17 March 2021`. after installing it, make sure it's added to our path.

Comment: When I do which dart, it points me to this /home/username/Framework/flutter/bin/dart

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when you have installed Dart-sdk two times. One time as a windows installer, and the other through chocolatey for instance. Uninstall the one you have in "Add/Remove programs", or at least make sure you only have one, and it should work.

Comment: do you know how I can search for this on mac? Im having the same issue and worried I have two dart sdks but can only find one

Comment: I have no idea, really, as I don't use mac - but my bet is to check the path in environment variables as this is were you probably get the location of at least one of the installations, if not both - in terminal write: echo $PATH